# move the instance collection to the point of contact with the plane?

Tags: geometry-nodes

the task is to move the collection of instances to touch the plane with the bottom point
[image]

Answer (score 6):

To do this, you would only have to send a raycast down to the plane.

[image]

Note that the center of the object is always the source of the raycast, so you have to compensate this additional distance with the offset.

Answer (score 4):

You can simulate¹ falling down² by raycasting down like in quellenform's answer, but then taking the lowest ray for each group (not island, because one Suzanne is 3 islands), and displacing by that much…

**An Animated Plane as a Base:**

[image]

**The Snapping Action:**

[image]

**A Demo:**

[image]

¹ - not a simulation zone, "simulating" means "pretending"

² - well, not the process, just the end result